# jQuery - Retreving submited form all inputs values

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter, dom

My question simply is:
How can i retrieve the value of an input of a specific form with jQuery !?

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($members as $member){
?>
<form class="form-final-record" role="form" >    

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $member->nid ?>" name="student_nid" class="from-nid">

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ++$i ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member->nid ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member->name." ".$member->surename ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="points" class="form-control" class="form-points" /></td>
        <td><select name="pass" class="form-control"><option value="1">Pass</option><option value="0">Failed</option></select></td>
        <td>
            <select name="absence" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected>No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </tr>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

as you see in the above code block, each row of my table is a form that includes some data of each person. i want to use jQuery AJAX function to submit their data without changing the page.

How can i reach each form's all inputs values ?!

in my jQuery Code i used:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $('.form-final-record').on('submit', this, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            nid = $(this).next('input[name=student_nid]').val();
            points = $(this).find($('input[name=points]').val());
            pass = $(this).find($('input[name=pass]').val());
            absence = $(this).find($('input[name=absence]').val());

            $.ajax({
                url: '../ctrl_amouzesh/students_final_record_action',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {nid: nid, points: points, pass: pass, absence: absence},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: well you will have your values in your inputs after completion of ajax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)

```
 $.ajax(
            {
            url: '../ctrl_amouzesh/students_final_record_action',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('.form-final-record').serialize(),
            success: function(data) { alert(data); }
            }
        )
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id attribute for your form

```
<form class="form-final-record" role="form" id='myForm' >
```

then use jQuery `serialize`

```
data = $('#myForm').serialize()
```

Comment: or `serializeArray()` if you want it as a JSON.

Comment: actually in this case, forms can't have ID , because it is impossible to make an ID for each of them, while forms are created by PHP foreach loop !

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
serialize does not submit your file input.
This will sumbit your form even there is file input.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),//set form action url at your form
        type: $(this).attr("method"),//set form method at your form          
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {


        }
    });
});
```